# Creating a new RANK based on delta of previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sequence

I've been working on an issue for a few days now, and I can't seem to find the right fix. Does anybody have an idea?

**Case**

We want to create a new a new sequence number whenever an employee has resigned for more than 1 day. We have the delta of the current employment record and the previous, so we can check the sequence. We want to calculate the min(Start) and max(End) of each employment record which isn't separated more than 1 day apart.

*Data*

| Employee | Contract | Unit | Start | End | Delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 1 | Unit A | 2014-01-01 | 2017-12-31 | NULL |
| John Doe | 2 | Unit A | 2018-02-01 | 2018-12-31 | 31 |
| John Doe | 3 | Unit B | 2019-01-01 | 2020-05-31 | 1 |
| John Doe | 4 | Unit A | 2020-06-01 | NULL | 1 |

With the query it should give back:

| Employee | Contract | Unit | Start | End | Delta | Sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 1 | Unit A | 2014-01-01 | 2017-12-31 | NULL | 1 |
| John Doe | 2 | Unit A | 2018-02-01 | 2018-12-31 | 31 | 2 |
| John Doe | 3 | Unit B | 2019-01-01 | 2020-05-31 | 1 | 2 |
| John Doe | 4 | Unit A | 2020-06-01 | NULL | 1 | 2 |

That is because sequence 1 end at 31-12-2017, and a new one starts in February of 2018, so there has been more than 1 day of separation between the records. The following all have a sequence of 2 because it is continuing.

**Query**

I've tried a few things already with lag() and lead(), but I keep working myself into a corner with the data sample that I have. When I run it on the full set it won't work.

```
SELECT
    Employee,
    Start,
    End,
    DeltaPrevious,
    Delta,
    DeltaNext,
    case
        when DeltaPrevious IS NULL AND Delta = 1 then 1
        when DeltaPrevious = 1 AND Delta > 1 then min(Contract) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY Contract ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
        when DeltaPrevious > 1 AND Delta = 1 then min(Contract) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY Contract ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    end as Sequence
FROM
    Contracts
ORDER BY
    Employee, Start ASC
```

Hope that someone has a great idea.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to use `lag()` to get the previous date and then do a cumulative sum.  This looks like:

```
select c.*,
       sum(case when prev_end >= dateadd(day, -1, start) then 0 else 1
           end) over (partition by employee order by start) as ranking
from (select c.*,
             lag(end) over (partition by employee order by start) as prev_end
      from contracts c
     ) c;
```

You mention that you might want to recalculate the new `start` and `end`.  You would just use the above as a subquery/CTE and aggregate on `employee` and `ranking`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Amazing how simple something can be when you are making complex solutions yourself :-). Added another variable to the second window function to separate employment records when someone changes contract type. (Hourly to Salary for example)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly from the definition of `Sequence` in your second table, you are more interested in the `DeltaNext` than in the `Delta(Previous)`. Here an attempt, including the code to create a sample input date with two more employees:

```
CREATE TABLE #input_table (Employee VARCHAR(255), [Contract] INT, Unit VARCHAR(6), [Start] DATE, [End] DATE)

INSERT INTO #input_table
VALUES
('John Doe',    1,  'Unit A',   '2014-01-01',   '2017-12-31'),
('John Doe',    2,  'Unit A',   '2018-02-01',   '2018-12-31'),
('John Doe',    3,  'Unit B',   '2019-01-01',   '2020-05-31'),
('John Doe',    4,  'Unit A',   '2020-06-01',   NULL),
('Alice',       1,  'Unit A',   '2020-01-01',   NULL),
('Bob',         1,  'Unit C',   '2020-01-01',   '2020-02-20')
```

First we create the deltas:

```
SELECT *
    , DeltaPrev = DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG([End], 1, NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY Employee 
ORDER BY [Start]), [Start])  -- Not relevant (?)
    , DeltaNext = DATEDIFF(DAY, [End], LEAD([Start], 1, NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY [Start]))
INTO #cte_delta -- I'll create a CTE at the end
FROM #input_table
```

Then we define `Sequence`:

```
SELECT *
    , [Sequence] = CASE WHEN DeltaNext > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
INTO #cte_sequence
FROM #cte_delta
```

We then group the same `Sequence`s by assigning a unique `ROW_NUMBER` for each employee with consecutive/ same `Sequence`s:

```
SELECT *
    , GRP = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY [Start]) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Employee, [Sequence] ORDER BY [Start]) 
INTO #cte_grp
FROM #cte_sequence
```

Finally we calculate the `min` and `max` of the contract duration:

```
SELECT *
    , MIN([Start]) OVER(PARTITION BY Employee, GRP) AS ContractStart
    , CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Employee, GRP) = COUNT([End]) 
OVER(PARTITION BY Employee, GRP) THEN MAX([End]) OVER(PARTITION BY Employee, GRP) ELSE NULL END AS ContractEnd  
FROM cte_grp
```

The `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT([End])` comparison is necessary or else the `ContractEnd` would be the max non-NULL value, i.e. `2018-02-01`.

The whole code with `CTE`s here:

```
WITH cte_delta AS (
    SELECT *
        , DeltaPrev = DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG([End], 1, NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY [Start]), [Start])  -- Not relevant (?)
        , DeltaNext = DATEDIFF(DAY, [End], LEAD([Start], 1, NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY [Start]))
    FROM #input_table
)
, cte_sequence AS (
    SELECT *
        , [Sequence] = CASE WHEN DeltaNext > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
    FROM cte_delta
)
, cte_grp AS (
SELECT *
    , GRP = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY [Start]) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Employee, [Sequence] ORDER BY [Start])
FROM cte_sequence
) 
SELECT *
    , MIN([Start]) OVER(PARTITION BY Employee, GRP) AS ContractStart
    , CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Employee, GRP) = COUNT([End]) OVER(PARTITION BY Employee, GRP) THEN MAX([End]) OVER(PARTITION BY Employee, GRP) ELSE NULL END AS ContractEnd  
FROM cte_grp
```

Here the output:

| Employee | Contract | Unit | Start | End | DeltaPrev | DeltaNext | Sequence | GRP | ContractStart | ContractEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 1 | Unit A | 2020-01-01 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2 | 0 | 2020-01-01 | NULL |
| Bob | 1 | Unit C | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-20 | NULL | NULL | 2 | 0 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-20 |
| John Doe | 1 | Unit A | 2014-01-01 | 2017-12-31 | NULL | 32 | 1 | 0 | 2014-01-01 | 2017-12-31 |
| John Doe | 2 | Unit A | 2018-02-01 | 2018-12-31 | 32 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2018-02-01 | NULL |
| John Doe | 3 | Unit B | 2019-01-01 | 2020-05-31 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2018-02-01 | NULL |
| John Doe | 4 | Unit A | 2020-06-01 | NULL | 1 | NULL | 2 | 1 | 2018-02-01 | NULL |

Feel free to select `DISTINCT` records according to your needs.